# Find the Length of the Bezier Curve having 4 Control Points

Tags: bezier-curve

I am unable to get the exact length of Bezier curve having 4 Control points.
   Please give your suggestion to calculate exact length of Bezier curve.
   Please explain more about k1, k2, k3, k4 in the below code.

```
double BezierArcLength(point2d p1, point2d p2, point2d p3, point2d p4)
{
    point2d k1, k2, k3, k4;

    k1 = -p1 + 3*(p2 - p3) + p4;
    k2 = 3*(p1 + p3) - 6*p2;
    k3 = 3*(p2 - p1);
    k4 = p1;

    q1 = 9.0*(sqr(k1.x) + sqr(k1.y));
    q2 = 12.0*(k1.x*k2.x + k1.y*k2.y);
    q3 = 3.0*(k1.x*k3.x + k1.y*k3.y) + 4.0*(sqr(k2.x) + sqr(k2.y));
    q4 = 4.0*(k2.x*k3.x + k2.y*k3.y);
    q5 = sqr(k3.x) + sqr(k3.y);

    double result = Simpson(balf, 0, 1, 1024, 0.001);
    return result;
}
```

Thank you Friends,
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

k1, k2, k3 and k4 are the coefficient of the cubic Bezier curve when represented in power basis. Namely,

$C(t)=P_1(1-t)^3+3P_2t(1-t)^2+3P_3t^2(1-t)+P_4
= k_1t^3+k_2t^2+k_3t+k_4$